# Ops Center LCM HTTP 401 with Public DataStax Repository

Tags: cassandra, datastax, datastax-enterprise, opscenter

I have installed Ops Center 6.0 on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS.

I am using Lifecycle Manager to provision a new DSE 5.0.3 cluster on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS using the DataStax Public repository.

Both Ops Center and the DSE cluster nodes are running in Amazon EC2

I have configured the Repository in LCM using my DataStax login credentials.

However, LCM is reporting HTTP 401 errors when attempting to access the repository.

```
2016-11-14 08:02:46,975 [opscenterd] ERROR: Received error from node event-subtype="meld-error" job-id="71c7e70d-3c1d-479b-b1e1-dabb71758c33" name="Cassandra1" ssh-management-address="xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx" node-id="20cbe1cc-61f3-4218-b73d-cdd71167d488" event-type="error" message="Received an HTTP 401 Unauthorized response while attempting to access the package repository. Check your repository credentials." (opscd-pool-0)
```

Here a couple of screenshots of the Job Details and Event Details screens:

[Job Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2qj6.png)
[Event Details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c96Ek.png)

I've checked that I provided the correct credentials many times now, and am pretty confident I haven't made a mistake.

Furthermore, on one of the nodes where the error is reported, I created a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.sources.list file with the same credentials, used curl to download the DataStax repository key, and successfully installed the DSE package manually. This suggests my credentials and connectivity to the DataStax repository are fine.

I'm currently a bit stuck, so if anyone can offer any help on how to resolve this it would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Austin

Answer (score 8):

OpsCenter developer here, this was a newly introduced bug in OpsCenter 6.0.4. We added an assertion early in the job to verify that repository credentials were entered correnctly (it previously took longer to fail and gave a more confusing message). Unfortunately, the assertion did not correctly handle certain special characters (like the '@' sign commonly present in datastax-academy account-names). OpsCenter 6.0.5 was released yesterday afternoon as a single-fix release to address this specific issue, and we've improved our test coverage to ensure this kind of issue doesn't slip through again.

Thanks everyone for your detailed reports, this SO thread was one important source of information that helped us characterize the bug to the point where we could fix it promptly.

Answer (score 0):

OpsCenter developer here, I work on LCM. It's hard to know exactly what's up given the information you provided, but some hints:

1. Post the full content of the job-event when. It might have useful context that you haven't otherwise provided.
2. Compare the /etc/apt/sources.list.d/datastax.sources.list that you created manually with /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opsc.list that LCM creates automatically. Apt requires that the credentials be provided in the URL, which means that special characters must be escaped. It's possible you have some special character in your password that needs to escaped but isn't. But even if it's not an escaping problem, comparing your manually created file and the automatically created one may give some insight as to where things are going wrong.
3. Ensure that you're using your Datastax academy credentials from https://academy.datastax.com/, and not something else.

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your response. I have attached a couple of screenshots to my initial post. Hopefully those provide some further context? I am using my Datastax Academy credentials and my password only contains upper, lower, and digits. I don't seem to be able to find the file /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opsc.list (or any file named opsc.list) on either the Ops Center server or the remote Cassandra node.

Comment: The additional context would be helpful in many situations, but doesn't help me here. I think you're going to have to drop out of LCM to diagnose this. Try running 'apt-get update' manually and tweaking /etc/apt/sources.list.d/opsc.list until things work. Once you know what's wrong, you'll have a good sense of what error you made (or what LCM is doing wrong). If 'apt-get update' is already working, then OpsCenter 6.0.4 has a bug in how it validates repository credentials and you'll need to downgrade to OpsCenter 6.0.3 in order to proceed with your job. Either way, please report your results.

Comment: facing same issue... Were you able to identify the root cause?

Comment: It's beginning to look like LCM in OpsCenter 6.0.4 has a bug where repository credentials that contain special characters (like the @ symbol in an email address) fail validation. The workarounds are to either use a repository-credential with no special characters, or to downgrade to OpsCenter 6.0.3. This is a serious bug and will certainly get fixed in 6.0.5.

Comment: Hi Mike, many thanks for your help. I can confirm everything works fine in 6.0.3 and this is an issue with 6.0.4.